# Including a second table Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-sql

I have a dictionary result that is returning a count of each checklist that is entered.

The classes look like this:

```
public class COMPLAINT
{
    [Key]
    public int COMP_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> Received_DT { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CHECKLIST> CHECKLISTs { get; set; }
}

public class CHECKLIST
{
    [Key]
    public int CL_ID { get; set; }
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public int COMP_ID { get; set; }
}
```

When I only return the _context.Checklists I get my total counts of what I want to be returned as below.

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Checklists

                .GroupBy(a => a.EmpID)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**QUESTION**
But when I add the complaints table, I get an error that EmpID is not in the complaints table, but it is in the checklist table. How do I include the complaints table and group by EmpID but, also query between the Received date?

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Complaints
                .Include(t=> t.Checklists)
                .GroupBy(a => a.EmpID)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've forgotten to include the COMPLAINTs property in checklist?

Comment: @RobertMcKee sorry about that, corrected.

Comment: What is it you want returned?

Comment: I want to be able to see all count of the complaints checklist grouped by EmpID received between 1/1/2015 - 1/1/2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still missing your Complaint property on Checklist, but assuming that was another oversight, this I think is what you want:

```
public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
  try
  {
    return _context.Checklists
      .Where(a=>a.Complaint.Received_DT>=start && a.Complaint.Received_DT<finish)
      .GroupBy(a => a.EmpID)
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I needed to add the complaint property on the checklist and when I added it, your suggestion helped. I added public virtual COMPLAINT COMPLAINT { get; set; } to the checklist property to fix my error to access the received date. Thank you so much.